# Detectar clic sobre <li>, no sobre <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una aplicación que despliega un menú si hacemos clic derecho sobre el div central (#cuerpo), en este div hay archivos representados en una lista `<li>`, cada `<li>` tiene como id `#fichero`. Mi problema es que a veces no hay archivos y si hago clic el menú se despliega (ya que hice clic derecho sobre `#cuerpo`).

Esto lo tengo programado asi:

```
  $("#cuerpo").bind("contextmenu", function(e){

...despliego menu...

  });
```

Solución facil? cambio #cuerpo por #fichero, pero no me funciona.

¿Alguien me da la solución? ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: Añade tambien tu html para que podamos ver la estructura y un [mcve] por favor

Comment: El id debe ser único, y dices que todos los elementos <li> tienen el mismo. Pon diferentes ids y una clase común y detecta el click sobre la clase.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de elemento es **#cuerpo**? Añade tu código html para que podamos entender tu problema

Answer (score 1):

El id debe ser único, y dices que todos los elementos `<li>` tienen el mismo. Pon diferentes ids y una clase común y detecta el click sobre la clase.

Ejemplo:

```
<div id="midiv">
  <li class="clase-li" data-id="1"></li>
  <li class="clase-li" data-id="2"></li>
  <li class="clase-li" data-id="3"></li>
</div>
```

Y luego detectas el click

```
$(".clase-li").click(function (){
  alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar... 

<li class='ficheros' data-id='.$id.'>Fichero1</li>



  $(".ficheros").bind("contextmenu", function(e){


...despliego menu...


});



Esto es lo que tengo actualmente y no me funciona

Comment: prueba  $(".clase-li").click(function (){
  $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e){ ...despliego menu... });
});

Comment: Tampoco, he probado a darle una clase al < ul > pero tampoco

Comment: Tengo que decir que dentro de #cuerpo, estoy cargando archivos.php, el cual tiene los ids #ficheros, igual esto tiene algo que ver

Comment: Te muestra algún error la consola del navegador?

Comment: No, pero he probado cambiando #cuerpo por otro div que haya en esa misma página y funciona, pero si pongo un div situado dentro de archivos.php que a su vez se muestra en #cuerpo, no funciona, osea que puede que el error esté en que el div#id tiene que estar en la página principal, con lo que se me complica bastante.

Comment: Pues tiene pinta de que va a ser por la estructura. En teoría una vez que estas detectando el elemento en el click deberías de poder lanzarlo, usa el click y un alert para ver si está. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Has comentado que dentro de #cuerpo tienes algo relacionado con php. Sin saber con detalle cómo está ese código implementado (sería muy bueno que nos pudieras copiar un fragmento más detallado del código como te indicaban en el primer comentario), es posible que tengas algún problema de bindeo. Si el .bind se ejecuta antes de que existan los elementos *li class="clase-li"*, el bind no funcionará, ya que no puede asignar ese handler a ningún elemento.

Mientras tanto, lo que podrías hacer para salir del paso es un workaround sencillo pero efectivo: dentro del bind implementar una lógica para mostrar o no en función del número de elementos *li* que tenga la lista. Es decir:

```
$('#cuerpo').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
  if(numeroElementosLista > 0) {
     mostrarMenuContextual();
  }
});
```

De esa manera, cuando no haya nada en la lista, no hará nada. No es la solución más elegante pero sí funcional que te permitirá no estar bloqueado a la espera de una solución.